# Automatically add user to newly created database

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-permissions

I created a user with reading rights on all the database created by an application in order to run reports.
The problem is that this application create a new database for every new projects.

Is there a way for this user to automatically get reading rights to every new database created on this server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the SQL Server instance is only used for this application you could add the user to the model database with the same permissions. Model is used as the... model for all new databases.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it will be used by other applications. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Since the DDL trigger don't work with dynamic sql, I decided to use the model database. No other application that create database will have access to this server in the future.

Comment: Just be sure that's well documented. Last thing you want is someone other than you creating databases there not knowing that the model has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a DDL trigger on CREATE_DATABASE see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx to log a row in to a table in a database that will remain constant.
Then create a SQL Agent job that looks for new rows in this table and executes a GRANT statement to give rights.  Once done flag the row as 'actioned'.

With this solution you can still filter the databases you want the action applied against.

Comment: I like that ! I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks for teaching me something new.
The hardest part will be getting the name of the database out of the event data...

Comment: Just leaving this here because this is relevant to the question and could help other people : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686998/get-database-name-from-ddl-trigger

Comment: I might be wrong but won't this add the user to all new databases on the instance too, just as adding to Model would?

Comment: No, I can filter the name of the new database to check if the program created it. But I was a bit hasty, it doesn't work at all.
To use a variable in a GRANT statement you need to use exec(), and you can't use exec() in a trigger... Back to square one, I may go with models.

Comment: Delayed response(!).  This is the reason I was suggesting using a SQL Agent job to perform the GRANT